# A user wrongly accepted my answer, what can I do?

Tags: support, answers, accepted-answer

[On this question today](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694757/libreoffice-loads-after-every-boot/694766?noredirect=1#comment1015735_694766) I was helping a user and after multiple attempts they fixed it there self and my answers did not work, however the user (I guess just to say thanks for helping me) accepted a wrong answer.

I left them a comment but they are rep 1 and may not return and I don't have enough detail on the fix to write an edit.

Is there anyway of getting this answer unaccepted if the user does not return any time soon ? Perhaps notify a mod ?

Comment: Very thoughtfull of you to mention. Your answer would be the most likely cause if it wasn't for the bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about it. :)

If your answer is wrong or misleading, you can - of course - delete it. But in this case, your answer is fine. Users are encouraged to accept an answer, and it's good when they do.

There are lots of questions where the accepted answer has fewer upvotes than the top answer, which is fine as well.